# Yii2 REST queryparamauth with rules

Tags: php, rest, authentication, yii2

As I know simple authentication for REST like in [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html)

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

But I want provide some rules to handle guest access? like access control from [authorization guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) like this

```
$behaviors['access'] = [
     'class' => AccessControl::className(),
     'rules' => [
            // allow authenticated users
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'actions' => ['some-action'],
                'roles' => ['?'],
            ],
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
            // everything else is denied
     ],
];
```

If I access `some_guest_action` as guest without `access-token`, it will be fine,

but if I access with `access-token`, `Yii::$app->user->getId()` always return `null` value

My complete code like this

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behavior['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
    ];
    $behaviors['access'] = [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
            // allow authenticated users
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'actions' => ['some-action'],
                'roles' => ['?'],
            ],
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
            // everything else is denied
        ],
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
public function actionSomeAction()
{
    return Yii::$app->user->getId();
}
```

Comment: You add in `User` class method `findIdentityByAccessToken`? You set `enableSession` to `false` and `loginUrl` to `null`?

Comment: @vitalik_74 thx for fast response, I have adding this config to my component in main.php        `'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableSession' => false,
            'loginUrl' => null
        ],` but still return null value :(

Comment: You add in `User` class method `findIdentityByAccessToken`?

Comment: Yes i have adding that function in `/common/models/User.php`, remove $behaviour['access'] `some-action` will return user->id correctly

Comment: May be your wrong write action name. Try that: `'actions' => ['some-action'],`

Comment: sorry, my typo :(,.. that question just example from action, my original action is `notification`

Comment: Finally i found the answer, https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4575#issuecomment-50977028 thx btw :)